# Xamarin project -- implement interface on iOS 11 only

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, versioning

I am working on a Xamarin app. I want a certain object to implement the interface IUIDropInteractionDelegate if and only if the app is running on an iOS 11 device. On iOS 10 or earlier, the interface is not available. The app also supports iOS 10. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There are answers on dealing with new features and backward compatibility [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974445/include-an-extension-for-a-class-only-if-ios11-is-available).

Regarding Xamarin, it's worth to try out `IntroducedAttribute` class.

```
[Introduced(PlatformName.iOS, 11, 0)]
```

You probably see it a lot while creating binding library. Class reference could be found [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/ObjCRuntime.IntroducedAttribute/).